# Adding attachments to email sent by a WordPress plugin

Tags: wordpress, email, plugins, attachment

I'm using a payment/email delivery plugin for WordPress named CP Contact Form with PayPal and want to attach PDF files to the emails, for this purpose, I am going to write my own plugin. There is a way to do this without accessing the third party plugin code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin has a filter for that purpose, use this code into your own plugin:

```
add_filter( 'cpcfwpp_email_attachments', 'my_pdf_file_function' ), 10, 3 );
function my_pdf_file_function( $attachments, $params, $form_id)
{
    $attachments[] = WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/uploads/my_pdf_file.pdf';
    return $attachments;
}
```

This way you can add an attachment to the CP Contact Form with PayPal emails without having to modify the plugin code.

Regarding to the parameters for the 'cpcfwpp_email_attachments' filter:

$attachments is an array of files to be included into the email, each item in this array should contain the complete path to the file to be attached.

$params is an associative array that contains the submitted data, using the field IDs as key (you can check the fields IDs in the form builder). It also contains $params["itemnumber"] to check the submission ID.

$form_id is the ID of the submitted form.

More info can be found in the CP Contact Form with PayPal plugin website.

Comment: Great! Thank you.  Already tested it and worked fine, however found some data into the $params that aren't part of the submission and doesn't seem to be documented. I can identify some of those parameters as the PayPal transaction details, will be great to have the full documentation for these.